bevel only the inside of the plane area without affecting the edges of the initial plane
I want to bevel only the inside of the plane area without affecting the edges of the initial plane from which I created it.
You can see that the plane is no longer perfectly square and is rounded by bevel tool.
I used blender 4.2 alpha version ...


Maybe extrude the outer edges and scale each of them on their axis?

not work with scale ... I will use an older version of Blender 3D ... but I'm not sure if the bevel edge will be fixed to have the same result . I tested also these changes but not work maybe is in development ... https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=h_9qtIEpa-4

I used an older Blende 3D versions with bevel edge to solve this issue.

Oh OK then    ;)  .................;
